# enforcing an envirnomental variable to a terminal/tty

Tags: environment-variables, tty, macos

I am running few remote ssh sessions

```
# ls /dev/pts/  
0  1  2  ptmx
```

One of the sessions running a live program, which depends on some environment variable(e.g. `$CATALINA_OPTS`).

I want to change the value of this environment variable and apply on fly to the running instance of the tty and the program in it. I do not want to kill the current tty or logout.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Terminals do not have environment variables.  Processes do.  This is a fundamental misconoception in this question.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for the link. It says its not possible directly, any other suggestions.